# Find immediate children and go no further using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I get the immediate children when searching for a particular element? For example, I want to get the `tr` elements for the table `t1`.

```
    <table id="t1" bgcolor="yellow">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>This is Cell 1</td>
                <td>This is Cell 2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>This is Cell 3</td>
                <td>
                    <table id="t2" bgcolor="red">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>This is Cell 1</td>
                                <td>This is Cell 2</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>This is Cell 3</td>
                                <td>This is Cell 4</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

I tried this:

```
'Count = ' + $('#t1 tbody').children('tr').length;
```

However, I get a count of 4, I don't understand why?

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/SvygZ/) is a full example:

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use:

```
'Count = ' + $('#t1 > tbody').children('tr').length;
//  or: $("#t1 > tbody > tr").length
//  or: $("#t1")[0].rows.length; // In this case, equal to previous code.
                                 // Warning: This also includes the rows from
                                 //  the <thead> and <tfoot> sections.
```

Your current code shows 4, because you have got two `<tbody>` elements in the table `#t1`:

```
<table id="t1" bgcolor="yellow">           <-- #t1
    <tbody>                                <--- tbody
        <tr> ... </tr>                     <----- Child 1
        <tr> ...                           <----- Child 2
                    <tbody>                <--- tbody (unexpected?)
                        <tr> ... </tr>     <----- Child 3
                        <tr> ... </tr>     <----- Child 4
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Ah! I was trying to be careful about the `tr`s that I forgot the body. Great an hour wasted. Thanks Rob!

Answer (score 1):

That is because with `$('#t1 tbody')` you get the `tbody` from both tables

You could use directly the [`Child Selector (“parent > child”)` <sup>docs</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/)

```
$('#t1 > tbody > tr').length;
```

and here is you updated example: http://jsfiddle.net/SvygZ/1/